# How to fix a single selection in antd select

Tags: reactjs, antd

My app supposes to fetch users and to save the in the input as a select.
My issue is that I can't save more than once in the input. When I choose the second person, the previous person disappears. How to solve this?

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-mestorf-f8t8q)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are resetting the value on every search. You should reuse your old state.value, check this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-surf-mhcxr

I recommend that you break the [state, setState] into multiple variable (one for each property in state). It will be easier to maintain/use in the future.

Here is the culprit:

```
    // set value here as well
    setState({ value: state.value, data: [], fetching: true });
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=5")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(body => {
        if (fetchId !== lastFetchId) {
          return;
        }
        const data = body.results.map(user => ({
          text: `${user.name.first} ${user.name.last}`,
          value: user.login.username
        }));
        // set value here as well
        setState({ value: state.value, data, fetching: false });
      });
```

Comment: Although the answer is fine, please add code snippets to your answer so the reader can understand the behavior without checking the external link

Comment: @DennisVash thanks for pointing it out, edited now :)

Answer (score 0):

When you write the state, dont erase the previous values:

`setState({ data: [], fetching: true }));` : will erase the `value` field since setState will replace the whole initialized object {value,data,fetching} by the new one {data, fetching}.

`setState(state => ({ ...state, data: [], fetching: true }));`: will preserve it.

```
 const fetchUser = value => {
    console.log("fetching user", value);
    setFetch(lastFetchId + 1);
    const fetchId = lastFetchId;
    console.log(fetchId);
    console.log(data);
    setState(state => ({ ...state, data: [], fetching: true }));
```

you can pass a function to setState.

By the way, why you dont call useState for each single state item to prevent this kind of issue ?

instead of:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    data: [],
    value: [],
    fetching: false
  });
```

you may do

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [value, setValue] = useState([]);
const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
```